# Randomize button that will show up

Tags: c#

I'm beginner in C# programming,
I'm trying to random button that will shown up when I press a button.
(I'm making a whack a mole games but using button as the mole and I want to random up to 2 button that will shown up)

```
private void Whack_A_Mole_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Visible = false;
    button2.Visible = false;
    button3.Visible = false;
    button4.Visible = false;
    button5.Visible = false;
    button6.Visible = false;
    button7.Visible = false;
    button8.Visible = false;
    button9.Visible = false;
}

private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    timer2.Enabled = false;
    button10.Enabled = false;
    btnStop.Enabled = true;
    button1.Image =(Properties.Resources.Mole);
    Random random = new Random();
    var randombutton = random.Next(1, 2);
}
```

This is what I do

Comment: What is your question? Please ask a question so that we can answer it, otherwise this may be closed without an answer.

Comment: Generate a random integer 1 - 9 and then use a switch statement to enable one of your nine buttons based on that integer.

Comment: I'm unable to discern what your trying to accomplish.  What is the issue your having?

Comment: Do you want know how to place up to two buttons at once onto the form at random intervals and at random locations? And also have the buttons disappear when the user clicks on them or when a certain time has elapsed without them being clicked?

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad english,

Comment: what I try to do is making whack a mole game, using 9 button that I have set in form, firstly i make the button invisible, then when the game start, 2 button will shown up randomly. but i'm confusing myself how or what should I do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way to handle this is by using a List of buttons. if you put all your buttons in a List, you can access them by index, removing the need for a large series of if else or switch case statements.

Declare a `Random` in your form, and then initialize it with your form. Do the same with a List of Buttons, and add your buttons to it. That way, you can change all of the buttons with only a few lines of code. Here's an example:

```
Random r;
List<Button> buttons;   

private void Whack_A_Mole_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    r = new Random();

    buttons = new List<Button> 
    { 
        button1, 
        button2, 
        button3, 
        button4, 
        button5, 
        button6, 
        button7, 
        button8,
        button9 
    };

    foreach (Button button in buttons)
        button.Visible = false;
}
```

Then, to display a button, you can use something like the following:

```
private void DisplayButton()
{
    //Ensures that the button that becomes visible isn't the other one already displayed
    int index;
    do
    {
        index = r.Next(0,9);
    } while(buttons[index].Visible);
    buttons[index].Visible = true;
}
```

The loop in there will make sure that a new button is displayed, but you should be careful with it. It's only meant to be used to show two buttons. If you call DisplayButton too many times without hiding any buttons and increase the size of your game, it can be inefficient, since it will select a button that's already visible more often. It works for your stated conditions, but I'd advise against using it in something scaled up significantly.

Comment: +1 for the list. But if showing a second button, you have to make sure you don't pick the same button again - a simple loop to pick a new one if the button selected is already Visible would work.

Comment: Edited to include a simple loop that will work provided the game isn't massively scaled up.

Comment: Hi, may I know what is "buttons" in here? i mean, I try to do the same but the error said buttons doesn't exist in current context. I'm sorry, i just start c# few days ago

Comment: My apologies, I missed a line. I've edited the code to include the buttons declaration.

Comment: erm.. sorry, it said that system.random doesn't contain a definition for next (for index=Random.next(0,9);)

Comment: Gah, I'm making all sorts of syntax errors today. Fixed.

Comment: If I were you, I would use a collection initializer along with a foreach :)

Comment: @nawfal Good idea, I've edited your suggestions into the code.

Comment: nah, this is perfectly make it. thanks for helping me out. how should i rate your answer in here? lol.. i dont know.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
random.Next(1, 2);  // this will generate only random number 1
```

to

```
random.Next(1, 10);
```

for generating random number between 1 to 9 and then use condition (Switch statement) to show the particular buttons.

and may be [Control.ControlCollection.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Method would also be helpful (if you have assigned name to buttons in a pattern) to find the exact control to show instead of switch statement.

```
var randomValue = random.Next(1, 9);
Button btn = this.Controls.Find("button"+randomValue, true).FirstOrDefault() as Button;
btn.Visible=true;
```

Comment: Please don't use a switch for this, it adds in so much unnecessary code. Also, quick note: the second argument of random.Next is an exclusive upper bound, so your first example will actually always return 1, and the second returns only 1-8.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
private void TriggerRandomButton()
{
    var randomButton = button1.Parent.Controls.Cast<Control>().FirstOrDefault(btn => btn.Name == "button" + new Random().Next(1, 10));

    //extra check to be sure we don't create an nullpointer exception.
    if (randomButton == null)
        return;

    randomButton.Visible = true;
}
```

It basically gets a random button from the parent control `button1`. `button1.Parent` should ideally be replaced by the actual container though.

Comment: this is nice and simple, i will try this one, thanks anyway